# Looping through Terms and Verify Google Account after hard reset

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, troubleshooting, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a recent Samsung Galaxy 6S Edge phone that had to be factory reset. After the factory reset it will loop through the 'Terms and Conditions' acceptance screen and the 'Verify Google Account' after I enter the Google Account email and password correctly. After entering in this information the phone will go back to the Terms screen and ask to verify the google account again. Google notifies me that the account was accessed through this phone.

Any thoughts of what the trouble might be?

Comment: The answer from my carrier is that I have to get a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait 72 hours, then try again and it will probably work. .. my guess is that you changed your google password, its a anti-theft thing that Lollipop 5.1 has.  anyways nothing you can do but wait for 3 days from the time you changed your google email password.  I had this same problem and figured out the reason after reading some threads.